# Exiting JavaFX application upon exceptions without returning through the call stack

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application, exit

I'm in the middle of writing a single user desktop application using Java FXML. I am relatively new to Java and JavaFX/FXML, but have a multiple year history with C and C++ as well as multiple scripting languages. I’m having some difficulty around handling fatal exceptions and have a question. I’m providing a little background on the application. My specific question is at the end.

My application is database driven and has multiple Java FXML screens, each with their own Controller. There is an application state manager that manages flow between a login process and the main app, and between the application screens. There is a screen manager that loads all of the FXML files and initializes the controllers, and handles displaying the screens.  I’m using log4j2 for logging, and plan to make use of it for any needed field debugging.

I understand about using Platform.exit() to exit the JavaFX thread and about using System.exit() to completely shut down the JVM. Those things work, but the way Platform.exit() works is causing me some grief.

What I've found is that Platform.exit() does not call the Main class stop() function until after the application has returned back through the call stack from the point where I call Platform.exit(). I need to have the stop() function before System.exit() is called so I can clean up database related items. In some cases having the application return up through the call stack isn't an issue. There are other cases where letting the code continue to run will cause confusion for the user, so I’m forced to bubble exceptions all the way back to the top of the call stack. In some of the scenarios bubbling all the way back to the top of the call stack is messy and is going to be hard to maintain. I can get more into why that is if requested.

My question is,  could anything bad happen if upon a fatal exception I call my own stop() methods to close any open screen stages and close database ResultSets, Statements, and the Connection, and then call System.exit(), without calling Platform.exit()? I've tested this. It does seem to halt the application without returning up the call stack, and so far haven't seen any major issues or memory leaks.

Thank you.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by the `Main` class `stop()` method. Is that on your `Application` sub class or someplace else? The JVM will exit when you call `System.exit()` so there obviously aren't going to be any memory or resource leaks. You may end up with leaving your db in  a state your application does not expect on restart, depending on how you've structured it and whether you are correctly using transactions.

Comment: For Java FX, the entry point to an application is the Application class.  Main.java has a  Main class  that extends the Java FX Application class. The `stop()` method is part of the Application class. When running a Java FX application the documented correct way to exit Java FX  before all windows are closed is to use Platform.exit(), which calls the `Main.stop()` method. I believe it also does other things I'm not clear on, which is why I asked my question. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?overview-tree.html)

Comment: After re-reading the Application class documentation again, I believe what I want to do should be OK.